# How to access .htpasswd in windows 10?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a Yii project and I have a .htaccess file.

That looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFileC:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd\
require valid-user

# supress php errors
# php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
# php_flag html_errors on
php_flag zlib.output_compression off

php_flag xdebug.remote_enable on

php_flag max_execution_time 600
```

So I check the pad of the .htpasswd in de index file, like this:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/.htpasswd';
```

with output: C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd

But when I try to run the application and I look in the log file I see this error:

```
[pid 11748:tid 2052] [client ::1:61735] C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AuthUserFileC:\\xampp\\htdocs\\yii\\sdi/.htpasswdrequire', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd\
require valid-user

# supress php errors
# php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
# php_flag html_errors on
php_flag zlib.output_compression off

php_flag xdebug.remote_enable on

php_flag max_execution_time 600
```

and .htpasswd:

```
hoi:hoi12345
```

then I still get this error:

```
[client ::1:61892] C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htaccess: AuthUserFile takes one argument, text file containing user IDs and passwords
```

Comment: Typo: You forgot the space between the directive name ("AuthUserFileC") and the value.

Comment: yes, oke, So I changed to: AuthUserFile :\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd\. But then I get this error: [client ::1:55599] C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htaccess: AuthUserFile takes one argument, text file containing user IDs and passwords

Comment: Anyway I don't see a file .htpasswd in the directory C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi

Comment: Why are you configuring Apache to use a password file that doesn't exist?

Comment: "So I changed to: `AuthUserFile :\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd\ `" - You removed the drive letter entirely?! (This is not a valid filesystem path.) And you have an erroneous trailing backslash. You should not mix forward and backlash (although both should work on Windows). The error you are reporting could perhaps suggest you have an issue with line-endings in the `.htaccess` file? ie. `...\sdi/.htpasswdrequire`.

Comment: After your edit you still have an erroneous backslash at the end of the file-path and you are still mixing forward/backslashes. Check your line-endings - are they consistent? Also, surround the argument in double quotes... ie. `AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi\.htpasswd"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this part of your code is not correct:

```
AuthUserFileC:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd\
require valid-user
```

Change it to:

```
AuthUserFile C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

If that doesn't work, try:

Change it to:

```
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Thank you. If I try this: AuthUserFile C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htpasswd. And I look in the log I see this: [Tue Mar 29 10:55:04.386029 2022] [authn_file:error] [pid 19732:tid 2052] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client ::1:55550] AH01620: Could not open password file: C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htpasswd

Comment: if I try it like I had before AuthUserFile :\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi/.htpasswd\. There was a type error indeed: AuthUserFileC. But ayway. Then I get this error:  [client ::1:55599] C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htaccess: AuthUserFile takes one argument, text file containing user IDs and passwords

Comment: But also if I look in the folder: C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi I don't see a file .htpasswd. But I see a file .htaccess. I don't understand that. What I see in the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\sdi is a other folder protected and in that folder there is a .htaccess file

Comment: `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` are two separate files. You need to reference the correct location (a full path) from within your `.htaccess` file to your `.htpasswd` file

Comment: Oke, I made a .htpasswd file and I restarted xampp. but if I try to f5 then the error stays: Internal Server Error.  
[client ::1:65432] C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/sdi/.htaccess: AuthUserFile takes one argument, text file containing user IDs and passwords

Comment: Maybe it helps if you repost the contents of your `.htaccess` here after you made the modifications to it.

Your `.htpasswd` file does contain one or more lines with usernames and encrypted passwords?